# Someone can help me about c# datagridview double click row

Tags: c#, winforms

I had a form which had a datagridview.I want if I double click at one row,another form will show.
Someone can help me.
Sorry because my English is not good.

Comment: subscribe to CellDoubleClick event of datagridview and open up a new window in it

Comment: Try this tutorial - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y8c0cxey%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the [CellDoubleClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.celldoubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick += New DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick);
}

private void DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.ShowDialig(); //To Show window as a dialog
    //frm2.Show(); //Normal window
}
```

Comment: And use `e.RowIndex` property to get the rowindex.